# How to keep track of updates to APK

Tags: updates, apk

I use only a handful of apk that are not from Google Play store (for whatever reason). For example Youtube Vanced, GCamera, Blokada.

But since they are not in the Play store, is there any way I can check if there are any available updates to all my "unofficial" apps?

I mean check from one place and automatically, not going to the relevant sites and checking manually every few days.